# Dúvida com variáveis

Tags: python, python-3.x

Olá, eu tenho uma dúvida, parece ser boba mas esta me atrapalhando, eu sei que em Python não é preciso acrescentar um tipo a variável, exemplo: nome = str("Python")
mas vejo algumas pessoas declarando igual o exemplo a cima, existe uma maneria certa ou errada  em declarar variaveis em python??

Comment: Python é dinamicamente tipada. O programador que fez isso que você exemplificou é um porco.

Comment: como assim? é certo ou não declarar o tipo da variavel?

Comment: Python é dinamicamente tipada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essa maneira não está errada. A linguagem Python lhe dá a liberdade de escolher. Inclusive as Aspas, que podem ser simples ou duplas, como no exemplo que você deu. Então pode usar str() ou mostrar o tipo,sem prejuízo para o resultado final.
Abraço.

Comment: Essa não é a resposta correta, a resposta correta é a do jsbueno, além do código ```str(...)``` ser desnecessário ele cria um overhead pois será criada uma nova instancia de str a partir de um objeto que já é uma str, ou seja, é um desperdicio.

Answer (score 5):

Então - como foi repetido acima, Python é dinamicamente tipada. Na linguagem, isso funciona por que na verdade, *tudo*  na linguagem é um objeto - e é um objeto derivado de "object".

Agora, ao longo dos anos, o pessoal percebeu que para projetos grandes, você ter dicas de tipagem que possam dar erro o mais cedo possível - de preferência antes do deploy, sobre os tipos de variáveis, pode facilitar o desenvolvimento e a leitura do código.

Então, em dois estágios: quando foi criado o Python 3, e mais tarde na [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/), foi introduzida uma sintaxe e ferramentas auxiliares para colocar dicas de tipagem opcionais. São as chamadas "annotations" - uma extensão da sintaxe que é usada em conjunto a biblioteca "typing" do Python, e ferramentas externas, como o [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/). Com isso é possível indicar os tipos de variáveis usadas como parâmetros de métodos e funções, e, [a partir do Python 3.6](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/), imitando as declarações de tipos de linguagens estáticas para as variáveis declaradas no corpo de classes ou de funções.
As annotations são colocadas depois do sinal de `:` onde aparece apenas o nome da variável, e a dica de tipagem vem depois disso:

Ex.:

```
def myfunc(a: int, b: int=0) -> int:
    c: int = 10
    return a + b + c
```

Nesse trechinho, anotei os parâmetros a, b, a variável c e o tipo de retorno da função "myfunc" com a classe `int`.  No entanto, essa declaração de tipo não tem nenhum efeito durante a execução do programa. Você pode colocar qualquer expressão Python válida 
após os `:`, o programa vai funcionar do mesmo jeito. O que ocorre é que há uma especificação da linguagem (pep 484) que detalha como podem ser construídas ferramentas externas que podem ler essas declarações e apontar possíveis erros de tipagem. Mas o uso dessas ferramentas é totalmente separado da compilação em Python ou execução do programa em si, e em geral é feito numa etapa anterior, em conjunto com as ferramentas do tipo "linter", para checagem de estilo.

Esse tipo de declaração não impacta na performance de um programa em Python, mas sempre vai haver mais considerações a serem feitas. Por exemplo: as anotações estão disponíveis, via introspecção, durante a execução do programa - e é possível *sim* usar uma ferramenta que obrigue que as tipagens estejam corretas em tempo de execução. O "mypy" que já citei não faz isso, mas seria perfeitamente viável. Agora,uma tal ferramenta sim, ao colocar verificações extras em cada chamada de método e função do programa acarretaria um impacto no desempenho que pode ser significativo - por isso a preferência pela verificação estática, antes da compilação.

Um outro fato que vale mencionar é que a linguagem cython, um super-conjunto do Python que compila a linguagem Python para C (e daí para um binário nativo), que já existe há anos, e aceita tipagem opcional - e no Cython sim, uma tipagem que faz diferença no tempo de execução, pôde a partir das mudanças do Python 3.6 passar a aceitar a declaração de tipagem disponível na sintaxe do Python, sem obrigar o uso de uma sintaxe separada, e incompatível com o Python para isso (o Cython tem a palavra chave `cdef` e outras que são usadas para declarar variáveis e funções opcionalmente).

Dito tudo isso, se você viu código como o que está na sua pergunta:

```
nome = str("Python")
```

Esse código está errado. Simples assim. Em Python alguns tipos de objetos podem ser declarados como "literais", isso é: há suporte na sintaxe da linguagem direto para esse tipo de objeto. Um desses tipos é string: em Python, a presença de aspas, simples ou dupla, ou as mesmas aspas ocorrendo trẽs vezes: `"""`, sem nenhum prefixo para as aspas já indica que o objeto será uma string como o valor que está entre aspas. Chamar `str("...")`, simplesmente está mandando criar uma string a partir da outra string que está dentro, não está dizendo o "tipo" de nada.

Até poderia estar assim, com anotações, como eu descrevi anteriormente:

```
nome: str = "Python"
```

Comment: Essa é a resposta correta!

Answer (score 2):

na programação temos um termo chamado (boa pratica) ou seja, algo que determina aquilo que é mais ou menos correto, veja que não uso certo ou errado, mas é aquilo que fica mais bonito, mais usual, fica mais claro para voce e outros programadores.
Em relação a declaração em Python, não é necessário declarar, e o codigo fica muito mais limpo não fazendo.
Veja se este artigo te ajuda: [Python: Trabalhando com variáveis](https://www.devmedia.com.br/python-trabalhando-com-variaveis/38644)